# Resources where one can find RD-171MV engine technical specifications? (e.g.TWR, Expansion Ratio, Isp, Thrust, Chamber pressure, O:F ratio)

Tags: engines, testing, soviet-union, historical-data, specifications

I'm trying to get a hold of various technical specifications for the [RD-171MV engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-170#RD-171MV)

> A modification of RD-171M being developed for the [Irtysh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irtysh_(rocket)) rocket. Unlike RD-171M it's completely made from Russian components and features a new control system. First test sample was manufactured in early 2019.

I'm looking for the "usual suspects", details like:

- Thrust/weight ratio
- Expansion Ratio
- Isp
- Thrust
- Chamber pressure
- O:F ratio

It would be great if I can find old as well as new data for comparison.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* I've adjusted the wording and formatting of your question to better fit the site, please feel free to edit further. In general it's always good to add to your question some mention of what research you've done first, in this case where you've looked first before asking here. You might even search this site to see if any information has already been provided. You've asked about RD-171MV but at the end you mention "old as well as new data", can you expand on that a bit and clarify what those mean in your case? *Thanks!*

Comment: I was trying to say that I wanted to get the data from RD 171MV's test. But if there are more than 1 tests, I wanted the data from first and last test so that I could what has improved or if anything has improved.

Answer (score 2):

> РД-171МВ — модификация двигателя РД-170/171...При этом тяга двигателя осталась прежней, а удельный импульс тяги стал выше.

> RD-171MV - modification of the RD-170/171 engine ... At the same time,
> the engine thrust remained the same, but the specific thrust impulse
> became higher.

Rocket engine tests continue:

> В ближайшее время НПО Энергомаш отправит в город Самару снятый с
> огневого стенда двигатель РД-171МВ. В Ракетно-космическом центре
> «Прогресс» (г. Самара, входит в Роскосмос) будет проведена сборка
> первой ступени ракеты-носителя «Союз-5», и двигатель пройдет еще ряд
> испытаний в составе первой ступени ракеты.
>
> In the near future NPO Energomash will send the RD-171MV engine,
> removed from the firing stand, to the city of Samara. At the Progress
> Rocket and Space Center (Samara, part of Roskosmos), the first stage
> of the Soyuz-5 launch vehicle will be assembled, and the engine will
> undergo a number of tests as part of the first stage of the rocket.

https://www.roscosmos.ru/32473/